# WPF is it possible to temporarily change the Visibility Dependency Property of a DataGridColumn without destroying the original binding?

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid, dependency-properties

I have a WPFToolkit DataGrid with at least one column bound (via a proxy object as columns are not part of the visual tree) to a property. I wish to toggle all columns to Visible so that I can perform a calculation based on the DataGridColumnHeader (which is only created when its column is visible for the first time). Having done the calculation I want to reset the column to use the binding that was previously set.

I've attempted to get and store the Binding Expression etc, but with no joy. I have also attempted to use the DependencyObject.SetValue() method to change the property value non-destructively, but this doesn't event correctly change the value, let alone retain the original binding.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `SetCurrentValue()` so that it won't clear the binding. `SetValue` destroys the old binding.

From MSDN:

> This method is used by a component that programmatically sets the value of one of its own properties without disabling an application's declared use of the property. The SetCurrentValue method changes the effective value of the property, but existing triggers, data bindings, and styles will continue to work.

Given you have this

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding TestProperty}"/>
```

The SetValue you will overwrite the binding with whatever you provide. If you call SetCurrentValue, however, will ensure that the property takes on the given value, but won't destroy any bindings.

Be aware that you should not use `SetCurrentValue` in your dependency properties' setter/getter.
`SetCurrentValue` is more useful in scenarios where you need a property to take on a given value but don't want to overwrite any bindings, triggers, or styles that have been configured against your property.

Comment: Thank you. I will accept this as the answer, but I'm using .Net 3.5 where this method is not available. I didn't specify that so your answer is valid, but do you know of a .Net 3.5 version of this? I can't see any candidates.